# why the posts queried from sql is more than those showed on the page?

Tags: posts, multisite, database, count, hacks

i am using WordPress multisite, the issue i face is that the posts queried from sql is more than those showed on the page, the details is as follows:

```
mysql> select count(*) from wp_137_posts where post_type='post';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 32 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.46 sec)
```

here i find there is 32 posts to the blog whose id is 137

but in fact when i open that blog, i can find only 30 posts including both published and draft posts.

why there are not 32 posts when i open my blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autosaves get stored with `post_type=inherit` and other objects such as menus are also stored in the posts table.

Comment: how to filter these posts using sql query

Comment: seems i have find the sql query string to do the thing i want, that is select ID,guid from wp_num_posts where post_status='publish' and post_type='post. btw, is there any useful links from which i can know more details about wp's database designation?